# Why check_output method of subprocess is only working sometimes?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I am using command something like below

```
l=subprocess.check_output(["python","abc.py","--a=2,5,6"],shell=False)
```

abc.py will internally call a web service on another server on which I can see the logs.

But that above command is generating logs sometimes and not other times even I did not change anything.

Could you please let me know the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is impossible to tell based on the information you provided why the request isn't going out sometimes.

Comment: I am executing that using pytest module and no thread are used. I hope this information is useful

Comment: and also when I try to print reponse code also nothing is printed but lines after that are getting printed and only one server running on that machine

Comment: Redirect all output from that internally called webservice to a log file, there may be some indications as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Also, replicate the HTTP requests that are sent from your program with something like HTTP Requester (Firefox extension) or wget (command line tool) to check if everything as expected.